# Inserting a character into the middle of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to be able to insert a / in the middle of a string, so this 125674567 ends up like this 12/567/4567.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert char into string at multiple positions sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115206/insert-char-into-string-at-multiple-positions-sql)

Comment: I have used the SUBSTRING method to display results, but I need to update the table with the changes. How could I do this?

Comment: If you got it to display, use the same logic to update it. What's the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

Couple ways to do this...

You can use a combination of [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [CONCAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) or as a user mentioned in comments above, the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) statement.